# pre_get_posts action doesn't work

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to load only two types of posts ( 'news' and 'reviews' ) in `home page` using `pre_get_posts`:

```
// Load Home Page Posts( reviews and news )
function search_home_posts( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'reviews', 'news' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_home_posts' );
```

But it doesn't seem to do nothing, since all post types and pages are shown in the `home page`. Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that code. It's correct and working fine for me on a default installation.

Change to using the default theme. Does it work now? If so, then there's something wrong with your theme.

Disable other irrelevant plugins. Does it work now? If so, then one of those plugins was interfering.

Eliminate the possible conflicts until the code works the way you expect it to work.

Comment: My mad, I was creating an other query object in the home template. You are right. It works perfect.